# Where is gravity settings in 2.91?

Tags: fluid-simulation, scene

I'm trying to find the gravity controls. I need to either turn it off, or change the axis. Everything I have found states its on the Scene tab, but I don't see it at all.  but no screenshots, and nothing discusses 2.91.
I've been through all the sub menus and...nothing.

I'm trying to have a fluid squirt out of a nozzle and remain horizontal until it hits something.

Thanks.

Comment: It's in scene properties for me... Maybe try load factory settings under the file menu (backup your current settings first of course)

Answer (score 7):

here it is:

tab on scenes -> gravity

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at the wrong tab. Silly me.